# Programmatically call anchor tag to Page Top at load time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a anchor tag that when you click on the "Up to the Top", it will move the web page to the top of the page. My anchor tag is #PAGETOP.

My question is, I am using the jQuery UI Dialog and basically would like to programmatically activate this #PAGETOP anchor so whenever the page always loads at startup, would like to ensure that the page moves immediately to the top of the page.

I would like to emulate the way stackoverflow moves to the top of all your questions when you paginate to the next page (if possible).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or take @Kip's idea and go pro with the [scrollTo jQuery plugin](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/). This plugin has additional options for different animations etc

```
<script>
     $.scrollTo( "#PAGETOP", 1000 );
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

To move to the 'PAGETOP' anchor in Javascript, use this:

```
location.hash = 'PAGETOP';
```

If you're wanting to do it on page load, in jQuery it'd be like this:

```
$(function() {
  location.hash = 'PAGETOP';
});
```

Comment: this is a fantastic solution for preventing the page from scrolling/jumping to an anchor tag on page load. Thank you!